# Bash error with '+' operand // Quotes misuse

Tags: bash, alias, quotes

```
☿[~]$ alias hdd='echo Σ= $(($(df -BMB /dev/sdb1 --output=used | tail -1 | grep -o '[0-9]*')+$(df -BMB /dev/sdc1 --output=used | tail -1 | grep -o '[0-9]*'))) Mb'
```

This alias suddenly stopped doing its job:

```
☿[~]$ hdd
bash: +: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")
```

But the command still works:

```
☿[~]$ echo Σ= $(($(df -BMB /dev/sdb1 --output=used | tail -1 | grep -o '[0-9]*')+$(df -BMB /dev/sdc1 --output=used | tail -1 | grep -o '[0-9]*'))) Mb
Σ= 3782845 Mb
```

Comment: `suddenly stopped` means `working previously`?

Comment: You've attempted to nest quoting operators in a way that doesn't work (apostrophes around the whole alias, and apostrophes around the regular expressions). As a result, your `[0-9]*` are in fact *unquoted* and subject to globbing by the shell, so the behavior depends on whether there are any filenames starting with a digit in the current directory. I suggest using `"[0-9]*"` instead, since the difference between apostrophes and quotation marks doesn't matter for the characters in your regexp.

Comment: sjsam, Yes, it worked before system update.

Comment: Wumpus, Thanks a lot!

Comment: (...while Wumpus's comment is right, by the way, I *also* have to consider Chepner's answer correct -- if you weren't trying to (ab)use an alias, you wouldn't have ended up in that situation in the first place. There's a reason anyone who asks about aliases in the freenode #bash channel gets, as their very first answer, "use a function instead").

Comment: ...well, to be *specific* about what people asking about aliases in that channel get told, with the timeline and person responsible for each revision: http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/alias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use an alias; define some functions instead.

```
get_space_used () {
    df -BMB "$1" --output=used | tail -1 | grep -o '[0-9]*'
}
hdd () {
    sdb1=$(get_space_used /dev/sdb1)
    sdc1=$(get_space_used /dev/sdc1)
    echo "$(( sdb1 + sdc1 ))"
}
```

This makes quoting easier, refactors duplicate code, and makes it much easier to pinpoint what the problem is in the event of an error. In your case, there was a problem with the second `df` pipe, since `bash` was attempting to execute something like `echo $(( foo + ))`.

Comment: Perfect suggestion ++